# about android google api-streetview

Tags: android, google-api

How to display streetview in android  AVD?
I write map.setStreetView(true); but only display blue outline.

Answer (score 9):

Also here is a site with an example in use (scroll down to step 7): 
http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-quick-tip-launching-maps-in-app/

You have to build the string using your long and lat points, and then launch a new ACTION_VIEW intent.

For example:

```
Intent streetView = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("google.streetview:cbll="+ latitude+","+longitude+"&cbp=1,99.56,,1,-5.27&mz=21"));
startActivity(streetView);
```

Answer (score 0):

At the bottom:

http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/g-app-intents.html

http://mapki.com/wiki/Google_Map_Parameters#Street_View

Answer (score -1):

You have to tell it *where* you want to view:

```
map.getStreetView().setPosition(latLng:LatLng);
map.getStreetView().setVisible(flag:boolean)
```

Comment: Sorry,your answer is not for android.
I think maybe my location not services.