# Android: using StreetView without starting an intent

Tags: android, google-street-view

I'm working on a simple android app in which I want to, once the user has clicked a button on the main screen, display the streetview of known coordinates.

I can create display a map like so:

```
    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    mapController = mapView.getController();
    mapController.setZoom(6); // Zoom 1 is world view

    GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(...);
    mapController.setCenter(point);
    mapController.animateTo(point);
```

Through this method, I could easily add my own buttons, overlays, etc over the map which my user could press to do certain actions based on their current location on the map.

I want to, instead of displaying a map, display a streetview with my own custom buttons displayed on top of it (along with the standard google ones). The only way I've found of displaying a streetview is as follows:

```
String uri = "google.streetview:cbll="+ latitude+","+longitude+"&cbp=1,99.56,,1,-5.27&mz=21";
Intent streetView = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse(uri));
startActivity(streetView);
```

Is there any way to start a streetview in a way through which it could be embedded into my application so that I could put buttons on top of the streetview which would allow my user to do certain actions based on their current location?

Many thanks in advance,

r3mo

Comment: You can use WebView see [here is demo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7586441/how-to-display-a-mapview-and-a-streetview-simultaneously/13717085#13717085) or you can [send an Intent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3447723/about-android-google-api-streetview/3773346#3773346).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way to start a streetview in a way through which it could be embedded into my application so that I could put buttons on top of the streetview which would allow my user to do certain actions based on their current location?

Not that I am aware of. `MapView` supports `isStreetView()` and `setStreetView()`, but I think that just draws the blue lines indicating where StreetView data is available.

Comment: how would you go about starting an intent to the google maps with the streetview enabled seeing as we cannot do from the mapView itself?

Comment: @molleman: See bottom table row here: http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/g-app-intents.html

Comment: @molleman You can use WebView [see here is demo](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13717085/703851)