# How to put streetView in webView in android?

Tags: android, google-street-view

I would like to put streetview in webView.
Something look like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7586441/how-to-display-a-mapview-and-a-streetview-simultaneously) But only streetView.
Any idea? I hope that somebody can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this code you can insert a streetview in webview. Your url must be an iframe like in this example. You can change the iframe size.

```
WebView web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web);
            web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            String streetWeb = "<iframe src=\"https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m0!3m2!1ses!2ses!4v1475148094565!6m8!1m7!1sF%3A-k265GybRcAQ%2FVH3MDcB3A9I%2FAAAAAAAAQTY%2FXZMeIk5IpDsLeewR7wwFhtS5wd6YqB9Gg!2m2!1d48.872337!2d2.777252!3f307.8785102665392!4f18.611126537609977!5f0.5032736111351279\" width=\"600\" height=\"450\" frameborder=\"0\" style=\"border:0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>";
            web.loadData(streetWeb, "text/html", null);
```