# Suppressing Google Maps Intent Selection Dialog

Tags: android, dialog, maps

When I use this code

```
   string url = "somegooglemapsurl.com";
   Intent mapLauncherIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,  Uri.parse(url));
   startActivity(mapLauncherIntent);
```

A selection dialog pops up asking if I want to open this map in the maps application or the browser.  I'd like the transition from my application activity to Google Maps to be seamless.  How can I suppress this dialog and tell android to open the map in the maps activity?

EDIT: When I get into Google Maps I want to open a directions prompt using public transpiration in a certain location.  I can do this through a google maps url, but a url brings up the selection dialog.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I haven't found a perfect solution, but this will at least open maps with the correct destination and public transportation pre-selected. Then all the user has to do is hit the directions button.

It also checks if google maps is installed and prefers to use that if so.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=0,0%20(Imaginary%20Place)&dirflg=r"));
if (isAppInstalled("com.google.android.apps.maps")) {
    intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
}
startActivity(intent);
```

```
// helper function to check if Maps is installed
private boolean isAppInstalled(String uri) {
    PackageManager pm = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
    boolean app_installed = false;
    try {
        pm.getPackageInfo(uri, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
        app_installed = true;
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        app_installed = false;
    }
    return app_installed;
}
```

Comment: Just a note - forcing Street View requires `com.google.android.street` package and `com.google.android.street.Street` activity; with intent as described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3447723/about-android-google-api-streetview

Answer (score 6):

Here are the different methods I found so far:

**1. Directly start the navigation:**

This explicit intent will directly launch Google Navigation:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=my+street+address");
startActivity(intent);
```

This will directly start the navigation (unfortunately without giving the user a choice of transportation means)

.

**2. Let the user select the transportation means:**

This will launch the Google navigation app, but lets the user select the transportation means before starting the navigation:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps/?daddr=my+street+address");
intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
startActivity(intent);
```

.

**3. Start on the Google map:**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q=my+street+address");
intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
startActivity(intent);
```

This will launch Maps, from where the user can start the navigation (and select the transportation mode).

In all cases, you should either use PackageManager and queryIntentActivities() or exception handling to handle cases where the user does not have Google Maps/Navigation installed.

In my app I use method 2 which works just fine. Hope this helps.

Add-on: Here's a method to check whether an app is installed or not. I use this to check if "com.google.android.apps.maps" is installed before calling intent.setClassName().

```
public static boolean isAppInstalled(String uri) {
    PackageManager pm = getContext().getPackageManager();
    boolean app_installed = false;
    try {
        pm.getPackageInfo(uri, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
        app_installed = true;
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        app_installed = false;
    }
    return app_installed;
}
```

Comment: I'd like the proper mode of transportation to already be selected for the user.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I'll just point out that getting rid of that selection dialog is not necessarily a good thing to do. You want to give the user as much choice in how they handle data as possible, that's part of the beauty of the Android ecosystem. That said, it isn't fair to judge without understanding your application, so...

You can use the `geo` protocol:

http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/g-app-intents.html

Instead of passing something like `maps.google.com/blablabla` format your URI like this`geo:0,0?q=my+street+address`.

Example:

```
Intent mapLauncherIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q=1111+imaginary+dr"));
```

Comment: I looked at that, but I need to load up google maps directions using public transit only.  I know you can do this thru a google maps url, but can you do this through geo?

Comment: Full spec is here: http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-mayrhofer-geo-uri-00 I'm not sure, but I doubt it. I've got another idea I'll look into.

Comment: Sorry I don't have any more time to look at it right now. I believe if you figure out the name of the maps activity you could start it using this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setClassName(java.lang.String, java.lang.String) `com.google.android.maps` is the package name, but I'm not sure of the Activity name. Then it's a matter of figuring out how to add the right extras. Not sure how to do that.