# Get indoor directions Android Google Maps API + Directions API

Tags: android, google-maps, directions, indoor-positioning-system

I'm trying to include in my app, using the Google Maps API and the Directions API, a way to show directions inside a mall from one store to another. If you use the stock Google Maps app in Android KitKat or a web browser, there's no problem on doing it.

However if you use the directions api with mode parameter set to "Walking" I get with the directions going out of the building instead of getting the route inside.

I've tried sending an intent to Google Maps app from my app and still the same. I've also tried copying the URL you get when calculating the route in maps.google.com, without fixing the problem.

Any help?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9084813/android-mobile-app-indoor-maps-walking-directions

Comment: I already saw that question but it doesn't awnser on how to implement this using Maps API, it only shows hoy to do an intent to open Google Maps App from mine. Even though thanks a lot!

Comment: Just saw that one a while ago, was in a rush so didn't get a chance to read the whole thing but it sounded applicable. I think the issue using walking is that it kind of looks at buildings to walkers like it does fields for cars. They aren't really valid, so it does what it can to get you to the closest valid route (which is out of the building). You'll prob have to use your own drawing methods to do this.