# DirectionsService: Add custom "travel modes" or "custom paths"

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, directions

I've created my own map with an own mapType.

Now on this map I would like to enable the DirectionsService (routing) but I need my own paths (not the streets/rails that the DirectionsService sticks to).

Can I add my own paths to the DirectionsService which should be the base for calculating the route?

I have so far found [this SO-Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9084813/android-mobile-app-indoor-maps-walking-directions) but in my case I want to create these paths "on the fly" and inject them into the map without uploading a static path to google.

In an ideal case, when I calculate the route, the DirectionService should use roads from Google Maps AND my own paths to find the fastest way.

**Example:**

Say I have a garden in front of my house with a maze and the path through the maze is not in Google Maps. Now if I want directions through this maze I would need to add the path somehow - otherwise probably the best the DirectionsService can do is calculate the straight line between the start and the end point.

Answer (score -1):

Not entirely sure what you mean by custom paths, but it sounds like adding [Waypoints](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/#Waypoints) to your directions might help. With it, you can modify the path that is generated from Directions.

Comment: as far as I understand, Waypoints can be added so a route passes through it (the path/street/rails must already be there). But let's say I have a garden in front of my house with a Maze and the Path through the Maze is not in Google Maps. Now if I want Directions through this maze I would need to add the Path somehow otherwise probably the best the DirectionsService can do is calculate the straight line between the start and the end point. I hope I could clarify(?)

Comment: No you can't. At least not with a documented API method. The Directions Service sticks to what the API knows as a walkable/drivable/etc. street or route.