# android google map navigation

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent, navigation

My question is I've a destination address, i've to show route to destinate location from current location with navigation of user current location.

I've tried some in stackoverflow only.. but not succeded. [**Maps with intent**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6560345/suppressing-google-maps-intent-selection-dialog).

how can i achieve this requirement.

THanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is how I do it

```
Intent NavIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=" + incAddress));
        startActivity(NavIntent);
```

intent starts up google navigation and gives directions to the address

Comment: Thanks.. it works for me. but navigation location is working with only gps is turn on but apart from GPS i need to choose network like getting locaiton from mobile network or wifi.